# Pass props locally with React-Router's #createElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

From the [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#createelementcomponent-props), where are the parameters `Component` and `props` coming from?

```
// default behavior
function createElement(Component, props) {
  // make sure you pass all the props in!
  return <Component {...props} />
}
```

Without React-Router, local props are passed into a component like so:

```
const myProp="prop";
<ExampleComponent myProp={myProp} />
```

How is this done with React-Router and `createElement`? Would you create your own `createElement` function in the Router file like so?

```
const myProp="prop";
function createElement(Component, myProp) {
  // make sure you pass all the props in!
  return <Component {...myProp} />
}
```

Then `myProp` will be passed to all components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you will not need to provide a `createElement` prop. The default behavior will take the `component` prop that you passed to the `<Route>` and render that.

From the [`<RouterContext>` source](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.0/modules/RouterContext.js#L92):

```
createElement(component, props) {
  return component == null ? null : this.props.createElement(component, props)
}

render() {
  if (components) {
    element = components.reduceRight((element, components, index) => {
      // ...
      return this.createElement(components, props)
    })
  }
  return element
}
```

In the render function, `components` is a `<Route>`'s `component` (or `components`) prop. The `props` are the props that will be [injected](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.0/modules/RouterContext.js#L58-L65) into the component, such as the location and any path params.

You would only ever have to provide this prop if you wanted to modify how the matched route components are rendered. For example, if you wanted to wrap each route's component in a `<Wrapper>` component, you could create the following `createElement` function.

```
function createElement(Component, props) {
  return <Wrapper><Component {...props} /></Wrapper>
}
```

Comment: do `componentS` refer to the `<Route>'s` component and its children? What is the reason for putting something into a component's props versus directly as a component's property?

Comment: React Router doesn't really use React to render route components. `<Route>` components are only used for configuration (they are converted into objects, which is why you can pass a `routes` object to your `<Router>`). For example, a location `/a/b/c` that matches `<A>`, `<B>`, and `<C>` components will first render `<C>`, then pass that as the `children` prop as it renders `<B>`. Then `<B>` is passed as the `children` prop when rendering `<A>`.

Comment: That is why your route components need to include the `children` prop in their render method. You can't really pass your own props to a `<Route>` component. The workaround is to use `React.cloneElement` https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.0/examples/passing-props-to-children/app.js#L55-L57